# Getting this error in my contactformpage

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, exception, contact-form

**Hi I am facing the following problem. Currently using Magento 2.3.3**

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Assignment1\crudform\Block\ContactForm' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'. Line: 821`

`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Assignment1\crudform\Block\ContactForm' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'. Line: 821`

**and here is my code**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Assignment1\crudform\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ContactForm extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns action url for contact form
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('crudform/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing numeric value from your namespace "Assignment1"

Comment: yaa. it worked now for me. Thanks :)